# Is there a way to fix loss of True values when rotating and shifting Boolean masks?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mask, scikit-image

I am using a Boolean mask when I shift it and rotate it I loose No.of  True values in the mask and no. of False values increase.I want all my True values to be equal even after shifting and rotating the Boolean mask. How can I fix this problem ?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import skimage
from skimage import draw

mask = skimage.draw.ellipsoid(12,14,25)

# padding the boolean array 

mask2 = np.pad(mask, pad_width = 50 , mode = 'constant')

# shifting the mask

shift1 = scipy.ndimage.shift(mask2, np.array([0,0,-25]))

# Rotating the shifted mask 

angle1 = 30
mask3 = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(shift1,angle1 , axes (0,2), reshape = False)

# Rotating the roated mask3 along different axis

angle2 = 45
mask4 = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(mask3, angle2 , axes = (0,1), reshape = False)

# Shapes of same mask after different operations

print np.argwhere(mask == True).shape

print np.argwhere(mask2 == True).shape

print np.argwhere(shift1 == True).shape

print np.argwhere(mask3 == True).shape

print np.argwhere(mask4 == True).shape
```

So the mask is an ellipsoid in the center of the array with all the True values . The values outside this ellipsoid are all False. 
In first step I pad the array with False values and make it larger . This has no effect on True values and I get same no. of True values in mask2 as in mask . Second step is shifting mask2 this is where my True values start to vanish Why ? How can this be fixed ? In next two steps rotating my shifted mask even lowers the True values. Basically by the end I lose my mask . Is there any way this can be fixed ?

Comment: Just as an experiment, try to rotate `mask3.astype(float)`.  This is part of the interpolation package, so it isn't simply shifting pixels.  It's interpolating new values.  This probably isn't the right rotation tool for what you want.

Comment: Trying  astype(float)  in fact lowering the probability of getting True values even further.

Comment: I'm not claiming it will keep the `True` values.  I'm trying to help you visualize how a pattern of True/False or 1/0 get smeared out when it's rotated 30 deg.  Imagine a True pixel being rotated to a spot that's between pixels in the target.  Do you make each of those pixels half-true?  Assign one pixel True and other False?  How should it choose?

Comment: I think I got some solution  from some code. So when I am padding the mask with zeros to make it larger. If I shift  d = np.where(mask2,1,0)  instead of just mask2 ,  which will give me an array of 0,1 values . This is similar to doing mask2.astype(int)  , which is much closer to your idea but instead of mask3 we do it for mask2  with datatype int. But I still get little bit deviation from number of True values on rotating the mask which is now not too much but still not equal in all cases . Only at angles 0, 90,180,270,360 I get equal number of True values in all cases.

Comment: Blacken some squares on a piece of graph paper. Rotate it and transfer the  pattern to a new page.  With 90deg it will easy. With 30 deg you'll have some tough choices.